# How to convert TBW into the number of write cycles single cell of SSD can survive?

Tags: ssd

Suppose I have 1TB SSD and specs say

```
1TB: 600 TBW
```

How to know the number of write cycles single cell/bit can survive?

It is Samsung `3D V-NAND 3bit MLC` inside `860 EVO`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, 600TBW is "600 terabytes written" so for a 1 terabyte drive the value *per cell* is, in theory, 600.

[Mathematic theory](https://s-cool.co.uk/a-level/physics/units-quantities-and-measurements/revise-it/homogenous-equations) tells us that equations should be homogenous. i.e. the units on one side of an equation should match what is on the other. We have two "units" in 600TBW - the TB (terabyte) and "written", and 1TB is self evident. In order to get "written" times we need to cancel the TB out of the 600TBW. That is achieved by dividing 600TBW by 1TB:

```
600TBW / 1TB = 600W (writes)
```

The same can be done for other sizes:

```
300TBW / 0.5TB = 600W
```

All you need to do is make sure the units match, so convert GB to TB and so on.

That doesn't mean that the entire drive will *survive* having 600 terabytes written to it from the host, as the drive may have internal routines that move data around for the wear leveller to work properly or you could have an odd write pattern that doesn't give the wear leveller time to work and hammers a particular spon on the drive. It also doesn't mean that it will "only" take 600 terabytes of written data. Flash cells degrade over use, but may last 650 writes or more, it's not an exact thing.